# MariaDB, SQL, how to show better resolution

Tags: mariadb, timestamp

I have written a stored procedure to perform a task, it works, however at the end of the procedure I want to show a summary which shows better resolution, this is what I have:

```
    SELECT
        CONCAT("Tickets requested: ", intTickets)
       ,CONCAT("Tickets reserved: ", intTicketsReserved)
       ,CONCAT("Start time: ", tsStart)
       ,CONCAT("End time: ", tsEnd)
       ,CONCAT("Elapsed: ", TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, tsStart, tsEnd), " seconds");
```

On entry to the stored procedure:

```
#Timestamp before we start
    SET tsStart = NOW();
```

At the end of the stored procedure before showing the summary:

```
#Timestamp now so we can work out elapsed time taken
    SET tsEnd = NOW();
```

The output only shows data and time with no microseconds, can I modify it to show the microseconds, this is what I see so far:

```
'Tickets requested: 2500', 'Tickets reserved: 2347', 'Start time: 2024-01-03 12:35:46', 'End time: 2024-01-03 12:35:48', 'Elapsed: 2 seconds'
```

I have already tried changing **SECOND** to **MICROSECOND**, that just causes the last column to show **2000000**, I would ideally like to see the microseconds after the start and end times and the elapsed to show seconds and microseconds as a fractional figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the microseconds, you have pass the number of microseconds (precision) to NOW():

Example:

```
set @a:= NOW(6);
set @x:= SLEEP(5);
set @b:= NOW(6);

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, @a,@b) / 1000000 AS Seconds;
+---------+
| Seconds |
+---------+
|  5.0150 |
+---------+
```

See also: [NOW()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/now/)

Comment: I don't have a crystal ball - since you didn't show us your stored procedure, here's a shot in the dark: Did you also declare the ts_start and ts_end variables as datetime(6)?

Comment: I've found the issue now, it was because I was declaring the variables at the top of the procedure, now I've removed these and used the same syntax as you, its ok.

Comment: note that for a stored *function* you would need to use sysdate, not now, since now will always return the time that the function began to execute.  same with a trigger.  no idea why stored procedures would be different.

Comment: if your session timezone uses dst, you want to use utc_timestamp, since now and sysdate return times in your session timezone, and if a dst transition occurs between the start and end, your timestampdiff will be very wrong